# Chemex Setting for Bay Area Costco Grinder Machines

Tags: grinder, chemex

I recently bought Peet’s ground coffee at Costco for the first time. It's too fine for Chemex (although usable) so next time I plan to buy whole beans and grind them at the store (sorry, coffee aficionados).

I live in the Bay Area and the machines say *San Francisco Bay Coffee*. Does anyone know what setting I should use for Chemex?

Comment: Don't the machines come with any instructions? Perhaps you could include a picture?

Comment: These are regular, big, in-store coffee grinders. They tend to have settings called Espresso, Fine, Drip, Automatic,etc. And within each one of those there are multiple degrees to choose from. So if Chemex might be Drip, I wonder what the sub-setting would be. I thought someone in the Bay Area might use the Costco machines for their Chemex. I'm also contacting SF Bay Coffee whose name is on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to go with a coarse grind for my Chemex, but ultimately, it should depend on the flow through rate and your desired extraction. It will always be fresher and more consistent if you grind it yourself and tune the grind to your brewing style. I dialed mine in by taste and timing, starting with the brewing recipe from George Howell Coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally use a medium-coarse blend from any burr grinder. I find that setting works fine for my Chemex carafe. That being said, it looks like you might want to use something in the Drip setting ranger closer to Automatic on Costco's grinder.